# Load testing our elastic cluster

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

We are currently trying to load test our app which involves a lot of logging to our elastic cluster. On heavy load , i start seeing the below error from ES

```
Error: No Living connections
    at sendReqWithConnection (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:225:15)
    at next (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connection_pool.js:213:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

and before that , we see another bunch of errors

```
Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:354:15
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:383:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

and

```
Error: [es_rejected_execution_exception] rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7@4d532edc on EsThreadPoolExecutor[bulk, queue capacity = 200, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@6c5897a1[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 200, completed tasks = 122300]]
    at respond (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:307:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:266:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:159:7)
    at IncomingMessage.bound (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\elasticsearch\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:729:21)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Is this just caused due to heavy load? I'm wondering how i can fix the bottleneck. We currently have 3 data nodes and 3 master nodes running on separate linux servers.

1. Should i bring in something like logstash? how many servers would i need?
2. Should i bring in a queue to set aside ES  tasks for later

EDIT : a bit more info -

1. We're performing one insert per request (we send around 100 parallel requests upto 2000 in total)
2. Cpu performance hasnt gone very high < 10 %
3. We hosting the machines in azure. All applications (node and es) stay in the same region

Comment: What did you try to test? Insert a lot of documents or query a lot of documents at the same time? You should start by monitor the elastic server. Are the cpu and memory enough? Then check the log if any slow query. How do your node app connect to elasticsearch, I mean is it local connection (LAN connection) or are they in different networks? Answering those questions may give you more idea on what to do next.

Comment: @DatTran - thank you , added more info

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your queue capacity is exceeded. It said that your limit is 200. You didn't provide the memory limit in your es server. But let's try increase the limit and monitor your memory.

edit `elasticsearch.yaml`:

```
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 500
```

As It's different in different scenario, I'm not sure but you need to workout yourself to test different ways.

In case, you have a lot of data to insert at the same time, you may consider using message queue like `kafka` for asynchronous handling data.

You can read more on this topic for more information about this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/any-idea-what-these-errors-mean-version-2-4-2/70690/4